# How to avoid connecting discontinuities in graphs when plotting data?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot a graph that has a discontinuity in the sense that it jumps from 180 degree to -180 degree at one point. Unfortunately, the points at 180 and -180 get connected. See the figures below.
(By now you might have guessed I am trying to do a lat-lon plot of a satellite ground-track.)

Plot MWE:
[image: Plot according to MWE]

Plot with real data:
[image]

**How can I *automatically* avoid the line that connects these two points?**

A MWE is provided below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            ytick={-90,-45,...,90},
            xtick={-180,-135,...,180},
            axis equal,
            grid,
            enlargelimits=false,]
        \addplot+[mark=,] table  {
            % A few points read off from above by eye...
              87   0
             100  75
             135  80
             180  82
            -180  82
            -135  75
             -90  35
             -45 -75
               0 -82
              45 -75
              90 -35
             100   0
        };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please specify whether you want data points (87,0) and (100,0) to be connected or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just insert an empty line to break the path

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            ytick={-90,-45,...,90},
            xtick={-180,-135,...,180},
            axis equal,
            grid,
            enlargelimits=false,]
        \addplot+[mark=,] table  {
            % A few points read off from above by eye...
              87   0
             100  75
             135  80
             180  82

            -180  82
            -135  75
             -90  35
             -45 -75
               0 -82
              45 -75
              90 -35
             100   0
        };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using Harish Kumar's image from the deleted answer:

[image]

Comment: Percusse, thanks. But is there anyway to do this automatically within pgfplots? This solution would require me to edit the data on the side of post-processing scripts or manually, which might not always be possible.

Comment: @Ingo It's best then to first read the table with `pgfplotstable` sort the table and then plot it.

Comment: Would you know how to introduce an empty line with `pgfplotstable`?